# How to configure APC for many sites?

Tags: php, apc

We're running many sites on one machine, with an `apc.shm = 4G`. This is not sufficient in caching everything, so we set `apc.ttl= 600` so that unused entries would get evicted. It's not clear if this is working as planned. We see a good cache hit rate of ~91%, but 100% fragmentation very quickly.

We also started seeing PHP go unresponsive which requires an Apache restart, but nothing is logged in PHP or Apache logs. Apache can still serve static files without an issue during this time. My gut tells me this is related to churn at APC in some way. Here are the current settings:

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    0
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /dev/zero
apc.num_files_hint  1024
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    4G
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 600
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    7200
apc.write_lock  1
```

A couple of questions:

1. We modified `apc.ttl` but did not change apc.gc_ttl at the same time. Would lowering this value help clear files out more quickly and reduce fragmentation?
2. Would we be better off leaving `apc.ttl = 0` and let APC empty and rebuild every time the cache fills?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
apc.num_files_hint  1024
```

this directive tells apc how many php files it is likely to have to keep in his cache.

- it is used as a hash key, so making it a prime number is recommended
- it is clearly not enough if you really have to cache 4GB of php files ! (shared hosting I guess)

so please start by putting a bigger figure here, like a prime number slightly bigger than this value :

```
find /var/www -type f -name "*.php" |wc -l
```

You may have a chance to understand what's going on by stracing the apache process which is handling your php scripts when apache goes unresponsive, using

```
strace -tt -o output.txt <pid of apache>
```

find the pid by using server-status page.

Comment: Correct, many Drupal sites on one machine so sort of 'shared hosting'. I will try upping this value. Thanks.